# CentOS, what repos can we use, and why would we use them?

Tags: linux, centos, package-management, repository

When I install CentOS, it is setup to point to the CentOS repo. Many things require the EPEL repo so I connect to that too. However, what repos are out there that I do not know about that might host very interesting software?

• Could people let me know the list of CentOS 8 compatible repos that they connect to, and what those repos might offer that is useful for me to know about?

• Is it possible for CentOS to connect to repos from Ubuntu (Debian I guess?) or Arch or other distros, or do they all have different package management standards so that it is impossible to use `apt` repos on a CentOS system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list of [third-party repositories](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) on the CentOS Wiki. You will find links to EPEL, IUS, RPMfusion, and many others.

> **WARNING:** These repositories are not provided nor supported by CentOS.
> The CentOS project has no control over these sites. Many have their
> own mailing lists, IRC channels, issue trackers, etc. for support
> issues with their packages.

Please note that they are **Community Approved Repositories**, meaning:

> These repositories are frequently recommended by the community, are
> usually well maintained and provide a substantial number of additional
> packages to CentOS. They are still not associated with CentOS but are
> independent. The above warnings about updates and priorities should
> still be heeded.

And no, you cannot use Ubuntu or Arch repos because they are different types of packages.

Comment: Thanks for this Bert. Can you tell me why I get "-1" downvotes for asking questions? I just can't imagine what kind of person is so opposed to discussion and learning and understanding that they want to do that. I asked a question, you gave me a good answer, and someone hit "-1" on it. For what? Are these people trolls?

Comment: Also, I appreciate the warnings, I get why they are important, and I would definitely heed these points for work servers, but for my home CentOS boxes, I'm perfectly happy to mix and match and try things out and possibly break things (I can just rebuild them) so that's perfect. The only thing that I would potentially be worried about would be security risks, things like viruses / ransomware etc. Do you think that these third-party sites are secure in that respect?

Comment: CentOS community will give those disclaimers about 3rd party repos to anyone. Some replace packages and seriously break things.  Also, Server Fault is for professionals. While sysadmins can do... creative... things, just for fun or beginner stuff may be more appropriate over  at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.